# Tag proposal: text processing

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that we have a *lot* of questions like this:

> I have this text:
>
> ```
>    sometext1
> ```
>
> How can I use vim to turn it into:
>
> ```
>    sometext2
> ```

I'm not really sure how to tag most of these. Frequently, they are asking about a specific approach, so we can use tag it with that approach. For example, [global-command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-command), or [substitute](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitute). But most of the time, the OP doesn't care (or know) how it's done. They just want to figure out how to transform the text from one form into another.

As far as I know, there is no general purpose tag for questions like this. I think [text-processing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) would be a good tag for this purpose. Do you agree? Should we add this tag? Is there a better name for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[text-processing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing) seems very vague to me; in essence, *all* of Vim is about "processing text" – that's sort of what a text editor is all about!

In your example, the OP would want to replace some text with some other text; so [search](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search), [replace](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replace), or both seem appropriate choices.

We do have [word-processing](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-processing), by the way, but that's more specific (e.g. using Vim to write a letter, book, etc.).